# Node is using parameters with hash: X but network map is advertising: Y exception

Tags: corda

When starting a Corda node, I receive the following error message:

> Node is using parameters with hash: X but network map is advertising:
>   Y.

What is the cause of this error, and how can I address it?

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your node's compatibility zone has pushed a new set of network parameters, and you need to accept them.

You accept the new network parameters by invoking the `CordaRPCOps.acceptNewNetworkParameters()` RPC operation on your node. `acceptNewNetworkParameters` takes as its sole argument a `SecureHash` of the new network parameters being accepted.

Comment: Hi @Joel  I am trying to call acceptNewNetworkParameters from corda shell but giving "RPC failed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch". I am passing hash of the network parameter found in HTTP network's map's signed-network-parameters folder, still getting same error...Can u plz help in this regard?

Comment: Can you raise a separate question describing your scenario, please?

Comment: Hi @Joel please find question with scenario at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630493/corda-network-parameter-change-with-network-map-service