# Corda Node shuts down with following error

Tags: blockchain, corda

[ERROR] 10:20:24+0530 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging.invoke - Exception during node startup: Node uses parameters with hash: 1DE6AD5577CA71D9307FC244B59418B09DACCF5F0C14B96C7D31E099A6C362C8 but network map is advertising: 4038BC9139ECE1C7B8E9E3F2029FFF5FB9FD0A9303F477EABFBBF98D134A2CF6. Please update node to use correct network parameters file. [errorCode=10znq16, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.0/10znq16]

Answer (score 1):

The node's network parameters file is outdated. How was the node built? If in dev mode using network bootstrapper, redeploying the node will generate the correct files. If using a network map server, simply request a new network parameter file from the network map service.

Comment: how we can request  new network parameter file from the network map service.

Comment: Please check the answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705320/node-is-using-parameters-with-hash-x-but-network-map-is-advertising-y-exceptio)